# unresponsive banner image carousel

Tags: html, css, image, w3.css

```
/* Full height image header */
.bgimg-1 {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("null");
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```
<!-- Header with full-height image -->
<header class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-grayscale-min" id="home">
  <div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="big-img.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="big-img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="big-img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
```

I used W3CSS business site template and added image carousel to the header. it works okay but doesn't give 100% height in mobile devices. its height gets smaller in the mobile devices. how to fix this?

Comment: min-height: 100%; of what? Probably you want to set only for mobile height:100vh